# Displaying a string array in Razor Pages?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to print out a string as a list in a Razor Page. I have the following:

`Aboud.cshtml.cs:`

```cs
public void OnGet()
{
    Message = "Hello";

    Message = AddToMessage(new string[] {
        "This is my first page",
        "By the end of this course",
        "I will be a Razor Pages Pro!"});


}


private string AddToMessage(string[] text)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (string txt in text)
    {
        result += txt + "\n";
    }

    result = ReplaceToUpper(result);
    return result;
}


private string ReplaceToUpper(string text)
{
    return text.ToUpper();
}
```

`About.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
}

<h1>This is the about page!</h1>
<br />
<p>@{
    string[] message = @Model.Message.Split("/n");
    foreach(string text in message)
    {
        <br /><p>@text</p>;
    }

   }
</p>
```

The page keeps printing out the line in one string. I've also tried using an unordered/ordered list as the HTML markup and I'm not able to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need other backslash so \n instead of /n

```
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
}

<h1>This is the about page!</h1>
<br />
<p>@{
    string[] message = @Model.Message.Split("\n");
    foreach(string text in message)
    {
        <br /><p>@text</p>;
    }

   }
</p>
```

Comment: Np made similar mistake a million times